# Absolute positioned element 100% width of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu 100% width of screen with my current markup seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/0nd5hL5h/

I've tried using the following styles on the .dropdown-menu class but it's causing a horizontal scrollbar, giving the body overflow-x:hidden is not an option.

```
width: 100vw;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -50vw;
margin-right: -50vw;
```

If you have any suggestions or can provide a solution without changing my current markup please share!

Answer (score 1):

Remove relative positioning from dropdown.

```
.dropdown{
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```

Center the dropdown against the body:

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu{
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Oh and, I recommend using `border-box`.

```
*{ box-sizing: border-box; }
```

**Edit:**

Apparently `100vw` takes the [entire viewport width](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Jan/0200.html) into account. Which includes the width of a vertical scrollbar. This makes sense in hindsight but seems like a bad choice in terms of the spec.

Either way, a quick patch is to disable `overflow-y` on the document.

```
html{overflow-y: hidden;}
```

Comment: This still adds a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Updated my answer, forgot I used `border-box`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zn065t5c/ Now, the fiddle will have a scrollbar because your website has a width set. The preview window of fiddle needs to be wider than your set width or you just need to preview this elsewhere full-screen.

Comment: Where's the live site?

Comment: After some testing the overflow isn't really a valid option because then I can't style the actual dropdown with borders or backgrounds without the partially being hidden by the scrollbar.